# What information does the topology of nonarchimedean Berkovich analytic spaces encode?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, non-archimedean-fields, analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

Given a finite type scheme $X$ over $\Bbb{C}$ we can associate to it an analytic space $X^\text{an}$. There are then comparison theorems comparing invariants of the topological space $X^\text{an}$ like the singular cohomology or the topological fundamental group with algebraic counterparts.

If we consider instead schemes over nonarchimedean fields, the analogous comparisons don't hold. Let for instance $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{C}_p$. Then the Berkovich analytification $E^\text{an}$ is either contractible or has the homotopy type of a circle depending on whether $E$ has good or bad reduction. This is encoded by whether the $j$-invariant is an integer. But for two transcendental $j_1$, $j_2$ there is an algebraic automorphism of $\Bbb{C}_p$ mapping $j_1$ to $j_2$. If $j_1$ is an integer and $j_2$ isn't, base change along the map changes the homotopy type of the associated analytic space. Hence there can be no comparison just like in the complex case.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a comparison between algebraic invariants and topological invariants if the reduction of a model modulo a uniformizer is taken into account on the algebraic side?
2. Is it possible to associate a topological space $\mathcal{X}$ to $X$, containing $X(\Bbb{C}_p)$ as a dense subspace such that the comparison isomorphisms known from $\Bbb{C}$ hold?

Comment: What topological space $(-)^{\operatorname{an}}$ are you taking? The adic space as in Huber? The classical topology defined by Tate is not a topological space.

Comment: I am taking the Berkovich analytic space. This is a locally contractible topological space. Adic spaces have spectral building blocks and are not suited to classical topological considerations. In a certain way the Berkovich analytification is the true analogon to complex analytification, e.g. for schemes over the complex numbers they agree. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your first paragraph. You can change the topology of a complex variety by the action of an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. To me, it looks pretty similar to what you describe over $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: The étale cohomology of $X$ will not change by the action of an automorphism of $\Bbb{C}$. By the comparison theorem with singular cohomology we can exclude examples such a the one I gave over $\Bbb{C}_p$. For instance all elliptic curves will yield homeomorphic spaces. I am not sure exactly how much the topology of a complex variety can change under automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}$, but there are some constraints that don't seem to be present in the nonarchimedean situation.

Comment: The étale cohomology does not detect everything, only for $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ coefficients. For the fundamental group, you will only get results about ts profinite completion. Serre indeed gave an example of conjugate complex varieties with different fundamental groups. Maybe have a look at François Charles' paper "Conjugate varieties with distinct real cohomology algebras" (https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3674) for a modern account on those questions.

Comment: For the Berkovich side of the story, you might have a look at the thesis of Pedro Castillejo: https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/handle/fub188/27694.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should have formulated my question in a different way. In spirit my question asks what information is encoded in the topology/homotopy type of the analytic space associated to a scheme + what invariants of the analytic space as a topological space are algebraic in nature. Your comments provide a good list of negative examples (and intuition for a nonexpert). I would still like to see some positive results. Question two is whether we can define analytic spaces in such a way that the results are uniform in the archimedean and nonarchimedean case.